# Polymer: Explanation for custom-elements with no template tag

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

In Google's Polymer Summit 2015 video, Rob Dodson talks about this `<todo-element>` which house only the property `todo` and no template at all. He said that this way we can create an element for our data.

Can someone please explain this design pattern or point me to some tutorial as I have Googled a lot about this particular topic but did not find anything helpful.

Comment: Could you please share the link to this Video?

Comment: @Adi I am on mobile right now but you can head over to YouTube and search for "Polymer Summit 2015"

Comment: https://github.com/Polymer/todomvc/blob/master/elements/td-model.html  check that out.